# wro4j minimize and empty .js files

Tags: javascript, css, maven, wro4j

I use Wro4j maven plugin to concat CSS/JS files and minimize it, then I've got one problem. When I use it, I received extra .js files without content (just "?" symbol inside) for all CSS files.

I use wro.properties like this:

preProcessors=cssImport
postProcessors=cssMin, jsMin

I tried anothe minimize processors (eg. yui) with same effect.

How to fix this?

Comment: What kind of resources are included? Can you isolate the offending js resource? It would help if you could provide a sample project which can be used to reproduce the issue